# Bash is not finding a program even though it's on my path

Tags: bash, path

I have a program on my path.  The program runs when executed with a full path specified.  But the program cannot be found when I run it with just its name.

Essentially, I want to understand how the below output is possible, and how to fix it so that my program can actually be found without a full path specified:

```
root:/usr/local/bin# ./siege
****************************************************
siege: could not open /usr/local/bin/etc/siegerc
run 'siege.config' to generate a new .siegerc file
****************************************************
root:/usr/local/bin# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
root:/usr/local/bin# siege
bash: /usr/bin/siege: No such file or directory
root:/usr/local/bin# wtf!?!?
```

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 using bash.  Also please note the warning output from siege is not relevant for the purposes of this question, as I am only interested in whether or not the program can be found and invoked.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Note the output here:

```
root:/usr/local/bin# siege
bash: /usr/bin/siege: No such file or directory
```

Bash maintains an internal hash of previously found executables in your path. In this case, it has details that at one time there was an executable at /usr/bin/siege, and reuses that path to avoid having to search again. You need to tell bash to manually rehash the path for siege like so:

```
hash siege
```

You can also clear all hashed locations:

```
hash -r
```

Answer (score 4):

Another cause of this problem might be that the path to the executable itself is on the path, instead of the executable's *containing directory*.

So instead of putting

```
/home/myDir/theExecutable
```

on the path, merely add this

```
/home/myDir
```