# Why is the "wrong" executable being run?

Tags: bash, path, which

I am trying to run [ipython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#introducing-ipython) from the [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Search-and-Execution.html#Command-Search-and-Execution) (version `4.4.19`) command line.

As a Python developer, I have various installations of `ipython` at various versions in various `virtualenv`s' paths, and so it is important to know which one I am running. Hence the `$PATH` is always changed when I change `virtualenv`, and this would a typical value for `PATH`:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/jab/.virtualenvs/tools/bin:/Users/jab/bin:/Users/jab/src/git/hub/jab/bin:/usr/local/gnu:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

The important detail in that is that the first entry is "`/Users/jab/.virtualenvs/tools/bin`", and that the file `/Users/jab/.virtualenvs/tools/bin/ipython` does exist:

```
$ ls -l /Users/jab/.virtualenvs/tools/bin/ipython
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jab staff 252 May 11 15:18 /Users/jab/.virtualenvs/tools/bin/ipython
```

As expected, `which` says that that file will be run as the "`$ ipython`" command

```
$ which ipython
/Users/jab/.virtualenvs/tools/bin/ipython

$ $(which ipython) -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
/Users/jab/.virtualenvs/tools/bin/python
```

However, that is not actually the case, and `/usr/local/bin/ipython` is run instead

```
$ ipython -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Can someone explain why `bash` is ignoring my `$PATH` and using the "wrong" executable? And what do I need to change (in [my bashrc](https://github.com/jalanb/jab/blob/master/src/bash/bashrc), or on my system (`macOS 10.12.3`)) so that executables are chosen by bash in the order determined by my `$PATH`.

Note: This is not a duplicate [Bash is not finding a program even though it's on my path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82991/bash-is-not-finding-a-program-even-though-its-on-my-path), because that asks how PATH works to find *any* program, whereas this question is anout why the *wrong* program is found.

Comment: The output of `(which ipython) -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"` gives `/Users/jab/.virtualenvs/tools/bin/python`. what does `ls -l /Users/jab/.virtualenvs/tools/bin/python` return?

Comment: FYI: the `python` (`pip`, ...) command runs fine: from the `virtualenv`.

Comment: `$ ls -l /Users/jab/.virtualenvs/tools/bin/python` gives

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 jab staff 42720 Nov  9  2016 /Users/jab/.virtualenvs/tools/bin/python`

Comment: What's the output of `hash -d ipython; ipython -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"`?

Comment: $ `hash -d ipython; ipython -c "import sys; print sys.executable"` gives
`/Users/jab/.virtualenvs/tools/bin/python`

Comment: Further invocations of  `ipython` (after running `hash`) keep running the "correct one" (from virtualenv)

Comment: The suggestion that this is a duplicate is *lazy*. The similarity is **very** superficial - they both mention "PATH".

Comment: I disagree. Both your question and the suggested duplicate show a command (`ipython`/`siege`) called by name, where the command exists in `PATH`, and the first result in `PATH` is not the one executed. The solution is also the same (use `hash` to force Bash to re-read `PATH`).

Comment: @jalanb Your command `$ (which ipython) -c ...` should actually be `$ $(which ipython) -c ...`, since you need `$(...)` for command substitution in order to use that. Maybe you should update your question to do that (or just use the full path `/Users/jab/.virtualenvs/tools/bin/ipython` directly, since there's no ambiguity there...)

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger Thanks, good catch (and bad paste!). Updated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like at some previous time in your bash session, the "wrong" executable is called an then its pathname is remembered by Bash (that's normal, such feature prevents further `PATH` lookups for already known commands).

To fix this you should run

```
$ hash -d ipython
```

This clears the remembered location of `ipython`, so Bash needs to search `PATH` again to find the command (and that's when it finds the right executable).

Comment: This works for me, and I have [updated my bashrc](https://github.com/jalanb/jab/blob/master/src/bash/cde.sh#L128)